# Discord.js - Rewritten version of a code for my music bot doesn't work

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots, audio-player

I'm having a problem with my music bot. The rewritten one joins and triggers the "Playing song" line, but doesn't play audio. The messy one works just fine. What could be the case-- everything is basically the same except these functions

Messy code

```
const videoPlayer = async function (message, song, skip, stop) {
    const guild = message.guild;
    const songQueue = queue.get(guild.id);
    if(!song && !skip && !stop) {
        songQueue.connection.disconnect();
        queue.delete(guild.id);
        return;
    }
    if (skip) {        
        if (!songQueue) return message.channel.send("There are currently no songs in the queue");
        const prev = songQueue.songs[0].title
        await songQueue.textChannel.send(`Skipping \`${prev}\`!`)
        songQueue.songs.shift();
        if (!song && songQueue.songs.length == 0) {
            songQueue.connection.disconnect();
            queue.delete(guild.id);
            return songQueue.textChannel.send("There are currently no songs in the queue");
        }
        var music = songQueue.songs[0]
        var stream = ytdl(music.url, {filter: 'audioonly', highWaterMark: 1<<25})
    
    } else {
        var stream = ytdl(song.url, {filter: 'audioonly', highWaterMark: 1<<25})  
    }
    const player = Voice.createAudioPlayer();
    const resource = Voice.createAudioResource(stream);
    await player.play(resource);
    songQueue.connection.subscribe(player);

    if (!song && music) {
        song = music
    }
    player.on(Voice.AudioPlayerStatus.Playing, async () => {
        await songQueue.textChannel.send(`Playing \`${song.title}\`!`)
    });
    player.on(Voice.AudioPlayerStatus.Idle, () => {
        songQueue.songs.shift();
        videoPlayer(message, songQueue.songs[0])
    });   
}
```

Rewritten Code

```
const videoPlayer = async (message, song) => {
  const guild = message.guild;
  const songQueue = queue.get(guild.id);

  if(!song) {
    songQueue.connection.disconnect();
    queue.delete(guild.id);
    return message.channel.send("There are no more songs in queue.");
  }

  const stream = ytdl(song.url, {filter: 'audioonly', highWaterMark: 1<<25});
  const player = Voice.createAudioPlayer();
  const resource = Voice.createAudioResource(stream);
  await player.play(resource);
  songQueue.connection.subscribe(player);

  player.on(Voice.AudioPlayerStatus.Playing, async () => {
    await songQueue.textChannel.send(`Playing \`${song.title}\``)
  });

  player.on(Voice.AudioPlayerStatus.Idle, async () => {
    songQueue.songs.shift();
    videoPlayer(message, songQueue.songs[0]);
  })
}

const skipSong = async (message) => {
  guild = message.guild;
  songQueue = queue.get(guild.id);

  if(!songQueue) return message.channel.send("There are currently no songs in queue.");

  let song = songQueue.songs[0];
  await message.channel.send(`Skipping \`${song.title}\`!`);
  songQueue.songs.shift();
  song = songQueue.songs[0];

  if(!song) return message.channel.send("There are no more songs in queue.");
  videoPlayer(message, song);
}

const stop = async (message) => {
    songQueue = queue.get(message.guild.id);
    await songQueue.textChannel.send('Stopping in just a moment...');
    songQueue.connection.disconnect();
    queue.delete(guild.id);
    return;
}
```

I don't get what the problem is-- please help!

## Edit:

**So it turns out, there's no problem with the code but their directory. For some reason, it just works on the original one-- I still don't know what the problem is exactly but it works now '^^**

Comment: does it throw an error or something?

Comment: No error-- that's why I'm quite lost

Comment: I'm new to javascript so that might be a problem--

Comment: One thing I noticed is that my bot stays for a long time in the VC, playing no audio but still there.

Comment: is that all the code?

Comment: No-- do you need it?

Comment: Tip when refactoring, do it one step at a time. Test that the step is functional before moving on. You'll eventually run into bug(s) that are causing your current issue.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I'll try doing it again--